# How can I apply CSS only to digits in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this html

```
<tr>
   <td>Test</td> 
   <td>324</td>
</tr>
```

My default CSS is `text-align:left`

But I want to apply `text-align:center` to any `<td>` that contains digits.

I have about 50 HTML files so I can't add class manually.

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: for each `td`, check its contents and add a class to it.

Comment: use parseInt() function in jquery.You can get number with this and apply css

Comment: What if a cell contains digits _and_ non-digits, like `<td>Test 123</td>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `filter` and some regex magic:

```
$('td').filter(function() {
  return /^\d/.test($(this).text());
}).css('text-align', 'center');
```

The above regex is a bit simple, if you need more precision use this one:

```
/((?!\w+[^\s]))\d+\1/
```

The above will match `(space)123` and `123(space)` but not `123a` or `asd 123` so basically only numbers and spaces allowed if that's what you're looking for. To add more valid characters just put them like `[^\s,]`, that will make the comma `,` valid too.

Comment: What about white space in the text, like in `<td> 324</td>`?

Comment: `<td>123123herp</td>` succeeds based on that regex, is that intentional?

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. Is there any way that if digits are more than 4 then this rule does not apply

Comment: Use this regex: `/((?!\w+[^\s]))\d{1,4}\1/`. Learn more at http://www.regular-expressions.info/. Regular expressions are super useful to learn and can be used in any language not just JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

old-school solution (works well):

```
function Trim(str){
    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}

function applyCssCustomToSomeTds(){
    for(i=0;i<document.getElementsByTagName('td').length;i++){
        var elementTd = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[i];
        if(!isNaN(Trim(elementTd.innerHTML))){
            elementTd.style.textAlign = "center";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
​$(function(){
    $("td").filter(function(){
        return (/^\s*\d*\.?\d+\s*$/).test(this.innerHTML);
    }).css("text-align","center");        
});​​
```

---

EDIT: here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Avf7P/

Answer (score 0):

As another example of adding a class through jquery you can check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VZWAP/1/). The class 'centerMe' just includes the text-align value that you need.

```
 $('td').each(function(){
            if($.isNumeric($(this).html()))
            {
                $(this).addClass('centerMe');
            }
    });
```

Note that this uses the isNumeric which may not be your intent. If that's the case then you'd need to modify this to use one of the regex approaches mentioned in some of the other solutions.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @ahren - Because I didn't paste in the text of my fiddle?